# Django - Static files not working correctly

Tags: django

In my project, I have a signup page. In the signup page, I have a link to a css file within my static folder. However the css is not being applied to the document.

Here is my code - **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Inside one of my app folders, I have a folder named 'static'.

I then refer to the files within this static folder in my document:

```
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'signup.css' %}">
    <h1 class="myh1">YO!</h1>
```

I have not run the collectstatic command as I am in development mode. Does anybody know why the css changes are not being applied to the html page? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you forgot to tell Django to look in your static folder actually

Let's say you've got an app called `my_app`. Regarding what you said, your directory structure would look like:

```sh
.
└── your_project
    ├── my_app
    │   ├── static
    │   │   ├── my_app
    │   │   │   ├── css_file.css
    │   │   │   └── ...
    │   │   └── ...
    │   └── ...
    └── your_project
        ├── settings.py
        └── ...
```

You need then to add the following line in your `settings.py` for every apps of `your_project`:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/' # <--- you did this one
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/") # <--- also this one
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    [...]
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_app', 'static'), # <--- you're missing that!
]
```

You were almost done, too bad!

Also, do not forget to make a force refresh of your page so you reload the cache (changes won't necessarily be updated if you don't do that in development!)

Comment: Hello. This works perfectly at first, however when I make a change to the CSS file and force refresh the page, the updated css is not applied.

Comment: Do you know why? Thank you.

Comment: Normally it should! A force refresh is `cmd+r` on a mac, and `ctrl+shift+r` elsewhere, are we talking about the same thing? If it works once, there is no reason it should not work after that! Also, look at the shell when refreshing the page: do you see your css file being effectively reloaded?

Comment: Oh I was doing cmd+r, however I needed cmd+shift+r. Thank you soo much man!

Comment: You're very welcome, dealing with static files can be such a pain!